# Using SSL with j_security_check on oracle application server

Tags: ssl, j-security-check

I need to secure my application on Oracle application server 10g. SSL is enabled and we have a certificate deployed on that server. the `web.xml` states the following

```
     <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>form</web-resource-name>

                <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
           </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>{{PUBLIC}}</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>


    </security-constraint>


     <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>{{PUBLIC}}</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

I'm using `j_security_check` in login.jsp . the problem  is i need to redirect users from http to https 
 http://www.myserver.com/myapp  to https://www.myserver.com/myapp
so i tried to use redirect rules and rewrite rule in appache but it didn't work i still have the same error

```
403 Forbidden
SSL (https) required for access
```

Is there any reason that rewrite rule or the redirect rule not working with `j_security_check` ?